# Programmatically create nested conditions in Magento catalog promotion rules

Tags: php, magento, nested, conditional-statements

Hope you can help me, I would like to programmatically add nested conditions to Magento catalog promotion rules, I have the following code:

```
$oMainCondition = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule_condition_combine')
                ->setType('catalogrule/rule_condition_combine')
                ->setAggregator('all');

        $oFirstCondition = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule_condition_combine')
                ->setType('catalogrule/rule_condition_combine')
                ->setAggregator('any');

        $oProdCondition1 = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule_condition_product')
                ->setType('catalogrule/rule_condition_product')
                ->setAttribute('sku')
                ->setOperator('==')
                ->setValue("2595040015");

        $oProdCondition2 = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule_condition_product')
                ->setType('catalogrule/rule_condition_product')
                ->setAttribute('sku')
                ->setOperator('==')
                ->setValue("2595040019");

        $oFirstCondition->addCondition($oProdCondition1);
        $oFirstCondition->addCondition($oProdCondition2);
        $oMainCondition->addCondition($oFirstCondition);
        $oCatalogPriceRule->getConditions()->addCondition($oMainCondition);
```

i would like to achieve the following:
one main combine condition, with condition ALL
this main combine condition will have one child; a combined condition with condition ANY
this child will have 2 children; A rule that a product SKU has to be 2595040015 or that a product SKU has to be 2595040019

(note; i realize that in this case it doesn't make sense yet to make it a nested condition, but I would like to get this to work before making my code more complex)

but; with above code, the following is only created:

1 main combine condition, with condition ALL
1 child combine condition, again with condition ALL (instead of ANY )

the 2 rules about my product SKUs are not coming back in backend at all.

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look at this article http://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/mini-tutorial-creating-shopping-cart-rules-programatically/

You need to use this block :

```
  $item_found = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
  ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product_found')
  ->setValue(1) // 1 == FOUND
  ->setAggregator('all'); // match ALL conditions
  $rule->getConditions()->addCondition($item_found);
  $conditions = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
  ->setType('salesrule/rule_condition_product')
  ->setAttribute('sku')
  ->setOperator('==')
  ->setValue($sku);
  $item_found->addCondition($conditions);
```

Hope this helps. I use the same way to create such rules.